# Mixin 0 (mixin 1) transaction ban

Tags: hard-fork, ringsize, ring-signatures, poloniex, hydrogen-helix

Does the network still accept mixin 0/1 transactions?

Did Poloniex update their transactions to use a higher mixin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the Monero 0.9.0 Hydrogen Helix release the minimum mixin is 2 (2 foreign outputs per ring for a total of 3) with the exception of [dust transactions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-is-the-technical-definition-of-dust-that-is-allowed-to-be-sent-with-a-mix). The minimum mixin will be raised to 4 in a future fork probably at the same time as RingCT according to discussions from the most recent [developer meeting](https://hellomonero.com/article/monero-bi-weekly-dev-meeting-note-highlights-2016-08-14).

The numbers above along with the simplewallet default come from [Monero Research Lab recommendations](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0004.pdf):

> Our recommended improvements to Monero include a protocol-level network-wide minimum mix-in policy of n = 2 foreign outputs per ring signature, a protocol-level increase of this value to n = 4 after two years, and a wallet-level default value of n = 4 in the interim.

Poloniex upgraded along with every other exchange and major mining pool and therefore abides by the new minimum mixin rules.